# Mouse Interaction in 3D space (ray)

Tags: xna, collision-detection, monogame

I use this code

```
    public static Ray CalculateRay(Vector2 mouseLocation, Matrix view, Matrix projection, Viewport viewport)
    {
        Vector3 nearPoint = viewport.Unproject(new Vector3(mouseLocation.X,
                mouseLocation.Y, 0.0f),
                projection,
                view,
                Matrix.Identity);

        Vector3 farPoint = viewport.Unproject(new Vector3(mouseLocation.X,
                mouseLocation.Y, 1.0f),
                projection,
                view,
                Matrix.Identity);

        Vector3 direction = farPoint - nearPoint;
        direction.Normalize();

        return new Ray(nearPoint, direction);
    }
```

to calculate a ray for mouse position x;y.
But the result is everytime again NaN..
If I try it with .99f it works but the collision detection is not exact..
How can I determine whether the cursor hits and model in 3d space?

Comment: This code looks correct. It sounds like there might be something wrong with one of the matrices or the viewport you're inputting. Could you show us how you calculate those, and how you call this function?

Comment: Hello Peethor, I fixed it. I had not updated the Ray and the view matrix(was 0; and 0 devided by n results in NaN I guess) ^^+. Now it works perfectly.  Thanks anyway ( =